# script is not allowed to send keystorke

Tags: applescript, keystroke

Applescript is not allowing to send keystrokes
is my error

my script is

```
set texttowrite to "[ep] t [ef] t [ed] t [ed] [ts] [ed] t [ed]"
tell application "Roblox" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    repeat with i from 1 to count characters of texttowrite
        keystroke (character i of texttowrite) 
        delay 0.08
    end repeat
end tell
```

`keystroke (character i of texttowrite)`  part is not working

Comment: The Stack tag-recommendation system is imperfect, certainly. ***Please*** look at the recommended tags before submitting a question: I find no connection to the [R programming language](https://www.r-project.org/) referred to with the [tag:r] tag (and frankly I find [tag:performance] to be likely unrelated).

Comment: If I substitute "TextEdit" for "Roblox", the script works. It does repeat the last character I one more time.  This is a VERY inefficient script. I'm guessing the point is cheating on some game, but there might be a smarter way to design the script.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go **System Preferences** --> **Security & Privacy** --> **Accessibility**.
2. Find application "yourScriptAppName" in the list of applications enabled to **control your computer**.
3. **Set** its checkbox.

If yourScriptAppName is not in list at all, then add it using button "+" of the Accessibility window.

Now, you can send keystrokes to Roblox.app any time.